# 404 error when accessing Content Delivery Web Service

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, odata

I am configuring one Content delivery web service jsp application. I have followed the online steps content delivery web service from Tridion 2011 SP1. 
I am getting 404 requested resource is not available when I try to access http//host:port/odata.svc. There is no exception in my stack trace. 
Steps to replicate.

1. Create a new jsp application.
2. Follow steps for "Installing a server role as a JSP Web application—universal procedure"
3. "Installing the Content Delivery Web service as a JSP Web application"
4. "Adding UGC to the Content Deployer server role"
5. "Setting up Content Delivery Web services for UGC"
   After this I try the link and it shows 404 error. 
   Please tell which file to upload to further debug this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the OData Web Service will be deployed "under" a URL, typically "ws". So you should try loading `http://server:port/ws/odata.svc` (check your web.xml to be sure).

Also, I would recommend deploying OData (and any of the other server types) from the pre-built webapps that are shipped with Tridion Content Delivery instead of manually assembling the jars - this will cause less trouble with missing files.

**EDIT** Adding a link to the Tutorial in Tridion World: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/deployer-and-odata-1.aspx

Comment: Do you mean I should use the cd_webservice.war file given in  \Content Delivery\roles\webservice\java\ folder

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Or you could just rename that to .zip, and copy the jars from there instead of "manually assembling" them

Comment: Hi I added the jars from the war file and added only the relevant conf files. When I try the url http//host:port/odata.svc, an IE blocker message comes. "Content from this website listing is being blocked by IE enhanced security configuration. And after that it says, IE cannot display  this feed. Even if i try the url /ws/odata.svc, it gives the same error.